# Внешний ключ равный 0

Tags: sql

**Задача**:

Таблица1:

```
  CREATE TABLE `olap`.`test1` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Есть Таблица 2:

```
   CREATE TABLE `olap`.`test2` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `FKtest2` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `id_idx` (`FKtest2` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FKtest2`)
    REFERENCES `olap`.`test1` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в таблицу 2 можно было заносить в поле FKtest2 значение 0, т.е. чтобы строке из Таблицы 2 была пока не поставлена строка из Таблицы 1

Comment: Зачем 0-то? Если связи нет, пишите туда NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ноль не получится - FK не позволит. А вот NULL - почему бы и нет...

```
mysql>   CREATE TABLE `test1` (
    ->   `id` INT NOT NULL,
    ->   `name` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    ->    PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test1
    -> SELECT 1,'name1' UNION ALL
    -> SELECT 2,'name2' ;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>    CREATE TABLE `test2` (
    ->    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->    `FKtest2` INT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->     INDEX `id_idx` (`FKtest2` ASC),
    ->     CONSTRAINT `id`
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (`FKtest2`)
    ->     REFERENCES `test1` (`id`)
    ->     ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ->     ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.42 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test2 (FKtest2)
    -> SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    -> SELECT NULL ;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test1 LEFT JOIN test2 ON test1.id = test2.FKtest2
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT * FROM test1 RIGHT JOIN test2 ON test1.id = test2.FKtest2;
+------+-------+------+---------+
| id   | name  | id   | FKtest2 |
+------+-------+------+---------+
|    1 | name1 |    1 |       1 |
|    2 | name2 | NULL |    NULL |
| NULL | NULL  |    2 |    NULL |
+------+-------+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```